# What's the difference whether you "implements OnInit" when you use the function ngOnInit

Tags: angular

When I use the function ngOnInit, TS lint warned me I should add `implements OnInit`. But I can use the function ngOnInit normally without implementing OnInit. What's the difference between the two ways?

Comment: here your answer https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5814

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume you are using Typescript

You don't have to add `implements OnInit` as this is TypeScript and JavaScript does not have a concept of Interfaces. So when you implement an interface, this does not actually exist at run time.

Implementing an interface gives you all the strong type checking, and the TSC will throw out any warnings.

So, I do recommend you still to use the interface for this reason, plus it's a good practice.

Comment: thx so much.I wanna ask u another question if u don't mind.actually,I am just a student,and i'm thinking about what's the meaning of tslint.Because I and my team's working for a company,the company buy a solution whitch use ng.But we did't know the ng.We start work with some demos.Now,we can product.But I used to use vs.whitch do not effet by tslint.now,I open the project with vsc,there are whole warn in my screen....so,I wanna know Why do I need the tslint?

Comment: Well the main purpose of TSLint is for coding standards, that way every developer working on the project is using the same standards and practices so everyone is on the same p[age. This also helps with best practices and helps prevent any bad habits

Comment: I keep seeing "good practice" invoked without any explanation about why it might be good practice to implement `OnInit`.  My theory is people say this because of type safety (or if you like, "typo safety").  If you mistype "ngOninit" on the method name, the compiler will not complain because that's a perfectly valid method name.  Whereas if your class explicitly implements `OnInit`, the compiler will complain that you didn't implement the required method.  So, implement `OnInit` and you will get some help from the compiler to make sure your code is doing what you want it to.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference. It's only good style to add `implements OnInit`.

`ngOnInit` is the only method this interface requires.

https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

Answer (score 6):

There is literally **no difference** between the two if you are talking about the **"compiled" version** (after TypeScript processed to runnable JavaScript).
The Interface will just be removed (there are no TypeScript Interfaces at runtime).
**Except**, the only real difference is that some **Angular Tooling** could make use of that information (static analysis, etc).
However if you do not use any Tooling this information is just for yourself, respectively for all coders of the project. You could easily remove that rule from your tslint config and **everything would keep working the same way**.

Comment: thx so much.I wanna ask u another question if u don't mind.actually,I am just a student,and i'm thinking about what's the meaning of tslint.Because I and my team's working for a company,the company buy a solution whitch use ng.But we did't know the ng.We start work with some demos.Now,we can product.But I used to use vs.whitch do not effet by tslint.now,I open the project with vsc,there are whole warn in my screen....so,I wanna know Why do I need the tslint?

Comment: tslint is an optional tool, which tries to help you and your team to produce high quality code. you can configure tslint the way you want in order to allow/disallow specific things. by using a very strict tslint config you make sure that your team is not "hacking stuff together", but working in a professional manner instead. however, this can of course be a problem for old projects where those rules have not been followed (like in your case). there is the same thing for pure javascript, called jslint.
you may just google jslint, respectively tslint in order to get a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the details.